# Error[Pe142]: expression must have pointer-to-object type

Tags: c, embedded, iar

I'm coding c in IAR Embedded workbench IDE. I have the following in a header file.

```
typedef union {
uint8_t payload;
struct UBX_NAV_POSLLH  nav_posllh;
struct UBX_NAV_STATUS  nav_status;
struct UBX_NAV_DOP     nav_dop;
struct UBX_NAV_SOL     nav_sol;
struct UBX_NAV_VELNED  nav_velned; 
struct UBX_NAV_TIMEUTC nav_timeutc;
struct UBX_NAV_SVINFO  nav_svinfo;
} UBXPayload;

struct UBXHeader {
uint8_t  class;
uint8_t  id;
uint16_t len;
uint8_t  ck_a;
uint8_t  ck_b;
};

struct UBXPacket {
struct UBXHeader header;
UBXPayload payload;
};
```

Here is my source file:

```
static char *c_buffer
void myinit( )
{
  c_buffer= (char*)malloc(50);
}
int myfunc(uint8_t c, char *c_buffer)
{
  static uint8_t rx_count = 0;
  struct UBXPacket *ubx   = (struct UBXPacket *)c_buffer;
  for(int i=0; i<3; i++){        
    ubx->payload.payload[rx_count] = c; /* Error[Pe142]: expression must have pointer-  to-object type */
    rx_count++;
   }
}

void main( )
{
  char mychar = 'h';
  myinit( );
  myfunc(mychar,  c_buffer);
}
```

The same **union** is defined as follows in another code sample written to be compiled with ARM GCC compiler. It compiles well & works well.

```
typedef union {
uint8_t payload[0];  /* here [0] is placed */
struct UBX_NAV_POSLLH  nav_posllh;
struct UBX_NAV_STATUS  nav_status;
struct UBX_NAV_DOP     nav_dop;
struct UBX_NAV_SOL     nav_sol;
struct UBX_NAV_VELNED  nav_velned; 
struct UBX_NAV_TIMEUTC nav_timeutc;
struct UBX_NAV_SVINFO  nav_svinfo;
} UBXPayload;
```

But in IAR C compiler giving error. Any suggestions please ?
I do not understand the following line

```
struct UBXPacket *ubx   = (struct UBXPacket *)c_buffer;
```

Comment: As evidenced by your comments to answers, this question is not entirely accurate.  It appears you have modified the union from the original code; the *original* code compiles in GCC, but this code will not work in *any* compiler.  You should detail your change - or better, just ask about the original problem rather than your flawed solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the `UBXPayload` union the `payload` member is a single character, but you use it as an array. And when you make it an array you make it an array of size zero so all writes to the array will be out of bounds, leading to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (so it's not working so well as you think it does).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I don't understand why similar code compiles in GCC compiler. what is the difference ? How to rectify this error.

Comment: @Armfan You fix the error by making `payload` a non-zero array. Either that do make it a pointer and dynamically (re)allocate when needed. And no, if it's not an array no compiler (not even GCC) would compile it.

Comment: Would you mind if ask you to refer to some code at the following link. Line number 97. 
http://reviews.openpilot.org/browse/~br=next/OpenPilot/flight/modules/GPS/UBX.c?r=80d7363dfa0bc5f92d26c9cd4bb737d576d25de8

I do not understand how it works.

Comment: @Armfan : In that case the payload member is defined in `ubx.h` as a 'zero-length array' thus `uint8_t payload[0];`.  [Zero length arrays are a GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html).  In this case you can safely define it as `uint8_t payload[1];` since all other members are longer than 1 byte in any case.  However if you access via `payload` outside the declared bounds, some static or runtime analysis tools may issue a warning.

Comment: @Armfan : Line 195 of http://reviews.openpilot.org/browse/~br=next/OpenPilot/flight/modules/GPS/inc/UBX.h?hb=true is relevant here - it is why the code works in GCC and why your's will not work at all (in GCC or any other compiler).

Comment: @Clifford I'm sorry if I have been confusing. Zero length arrays not supported in IAR c. I did not know how to solve this problem, hence asked for help here. Using `payload[1]' in the struct, I'm getting problems.

Comment: @Armfan - I'm not confused - it is perfectly clear to me that IAR is ISO compliant in this respect and that GCC is not. Using `payload[1]` is the solution, and any problems it causes are probably easier to solve that *invalid code* that *won't compile*!  Unless you are forthcoming about the problems it causes you cannot be helped further.  Perhaps a new question about the new problem should be posted.